# Smoothing ESC input to IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, noise

For an RC (model) car, I'm trying to make reversing lights, brake lights and indicators. When the car is going forwards, the brake lights need to go off, and when it reverses then both the brake lights and the indicators need to turn off. I'm using the ESC (Electronic Speed Control) output and an IC(Integrated Circuit) to determine which lights should be on when the esc output is one way or another. This is the (relevant part of the) circuit diagram:
[image: Circuit]

At the moment, the circuit works but at low input voltage to the IC (i.e. at low revs) the brake and indicators don't turn off completely, but flash. At max. revs the both do turn off though. I've adjusted the IC input (am using an ADC port to be able to detect the low voltages) to a very low input, so this is not the problem.

My question: what is the best way to smooth out the DC signal coming from the ESC, so I can make the inputs to the IC more responsive? I've looked at rectifier circuits but they all seem to apply for AC. There must be a similar kind of idea for DC circuits surely.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do the brake lights and indicators need to come on in reverse? It's just an RC car and not a porsche.

Comment: Just an RC car? It is all about the details.

Comment: It is indeed. Lights make it look so much nicer. And the little details such as the indicators switching off when in reverse just adds to it

Comment: What is this mysterious "IC", and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: IC? The ATtiny84A-PU to be specific. I'm using it for the logic gate. A lot easier to do with an IC than with traditional components

Comment: Since you are using a micro anyway, why not monitor the PWM input to the ESC and drive your lights based on that?   You will have an additional neutral set point to independently calibrate but it shouldn't be too hard.  Or you may be able to find spare output pins on the ESC's micro and reflash it to include this functionality.  Incidentally, the "E" in "ESC" is for "Electronic" not "Engine".

Comment: I've not actually used PWM input on an AVR before, and from the looks of it it's relatively complicated. If there is no other solution I guess that's the best way forward, as it should be more accurate.

Comment: Actually, If I use a low pass filter to convert the PWM signal from the receiver to analog, I could easily use the ADC function on the IC. Am just wondering though, will the low pass filter be able to respond to the variation in PWM input (freq. of 1kHz) quickly enough?

Comment: Conversion of a servo PWM signal to analog is a bad idea as it is relatively infrequent.  Use the digital timing capabilities in the micro to measure it, the same way any ESC has for the past 15+ years.

Comment: In that case, I'll have a go at using the PWM input. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I fixed the problem by using a 2.2uF bypass cap in parallel to the IC input. Now the input signal to the IC is 'smoother' and so the flashing does not occur anymore. Thanks for all the suggestions!